# Golang и "concurrency"

Tags: golang

На официальной [русской страничке документации](https://code.google.com/p/golang-ru/) Golang сообщается:

> Термин "concurrency" в
>   программировании, судя по всему, не
>   имеет точного аналога в русском языке.
>   Хотя многие переводят его как
>   "параллелизм", это ошибка (см.
>   Parallelism is not concurrency), так
>   же как в математике "concurrent lines"
>   — вовсе не "параллельные прямые", а
>   прямые, имеющие общую точку. Русский
>   язык резиновый, он выдержит еще один
>   термин: "конкарентность",
>   "конкарентный".

Это замечание, тем не менее, совершенно не раскрывает само понятие и суть явления этого "concurrency". В чем оно заключается?

Дополнение:
С учетом вот [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095751/understanding-goroutines), я так понимаю, что goroutine НЕ выполняются параллельно (не в геометрическом, а в смысле одновременного выполнения). Только как это все работает и что под этим подразумевается все равно не понимается.

Answer (score 8):

Заключается в том, что в каком-то месте программы образуется «вилка» из нитей выполнения кода. Т.е. до этого места логическая цепочка была одна и последовательная, но в этом месте она раздваивается и дальше идёт уже две логических цепочки последовательных действий, выполняемых параллельно. Далее, обычно, они сливаются обратно, либо какие-то ветви просто прекращают существовать отработав свою логику.

Т.е. термин достаточно точный, просто непосвящённый человек может подумать в рамках геометрии, что раз параллельные потоки, то они не пересекаются, а это не совсем так. Они параллельны не везде.

Comment: > действий, выполняемых параллельно.

Я думаю, здесь вы не правы. См. дополнение к моему вопросу.

Comment: Мне кажется особых противоречий нет, скорее есть несовершенство реализации этого функционала (а может это и умышленно сделано…). Т.е. есть возможность зависания потоков в случае если в них вызываются системные блокирующие вызовы типа fmt.Prinln а в остальном всё так и есть — они выполняются параллельно, просто на такие вещи нужно обращать внимание, а то поток может залипнуть…

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю: в определенной точке выполнения программы пошло разветвление: горутина и основной код; т.к. все это выполняется в одном системном потоке/процессе, то все это работает через какой-то свой внутренний шедуллер, который поочередно выполняет код из этих псевдопотоков?

Comment: qnub, все разобрался. Благодарю за соучастие.

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить о примере из Вашего вопроса, то там проблема заключается в том что одина рутина пишет в переменную в инфинити лупе, в то время как другая рутина пытается получить доступ к той же переменной(как я это вижу).
Если, к примеру, поставить паузу в цикле который пишет в переменную, то main будет выводить новое значение переменной:

```
type myInt struct {
    Value int64
}

func (i *myInt) add(x int64) int64 {
    i.Value += x
    return i.Value
}

func (i *myInt) setValue(x int64) {
    i.Value = x
}

func (i *myInt) getValue() int64 {
    return i.Value
}

var x myInt

func inc_x() { //test
    for {
        x.add(1)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Nanosecond)
    }
}

func main() {
    go inc_x()
    for {
        fmt.Print("x=")
        fmt.Println(x.getValue())
        //      time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```